# Eclipse, android app[How TO] open TXT file [CODE]?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i want Some Code for eclipse to open file from internal storage, from Root directory and from system location.

can anyone help me?

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The below lines may be what you wanted.

```
public static String readFromFile(String filePath){
    String total="";
    File file=new File(filePath);
      try {
        String encoding="GBK";
              if(file.isFile() && file.exists()){ //判断文件是否存在
               InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(file),encoding);//考虑到汉子编码格式
               BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(read);
               String lineTxt = null;
               while((lineTxt = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                   total+=lineTxt;
               }
               read.close();
      }else if(!file.exists())
      {
        file.createNewFile();
      }
      } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("读取文件内容出错");
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     return total;
     }
```

Comment: if you want to read system files,you may learn something abour linux,you can get the root pemession by using these codes:             Process process = null; 

try{ 
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 
process.waitFor(); 
}catch(Exception e){ 

   e.printStackTrace(); 

}finally { 
   process.destroy(); 
}